# Javascript .setTimeout() how to refer to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these codes:

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $title = $(this).attr('title');
        $.get('getOutput', {}, function(){
            // success ajax get                
            // how to refer again to this function? Doing again the $('.btn').click event
            setTimeout(// $('.btn').click(), 100);
        });
    });
})
```

I want to repeat the click event of the button. But my main question is, how would you refer the right function or event in `setTimeout()` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it into an anonymous function.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.btn').click();
}, 100);
```

In case you want to trigger the event in the specific element you've clicked before, you'll need to store the current element in a variable since `this` value inside the anonymous function would be different.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    // ...your code...
    setTimeout(function() {
        $el.click();
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: but i have many elements like `$('.btn')`
it might be confused to what to what element it would try to select.

Comment: @user2975385 I've edited the answer to regard your question. ;)

Comment: does 100 miliseconds not a problem? :(
because you knew that i have ajax call like that, won't it be lag?

this answer is working, the codes are working, but when i try to open many of it, it gave lag.

Comment: I don't think it would cause any lag in this case.

Comment: yep, it's not lagging when i try to click at one $('.btn');
but when i tried clicking on the second $('.btn')
 it is starting to lag.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the time out call back in an anonymous function and just real call the click function in there.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $(".btn").click(); 
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `this` inside the anonymous function with `$.proxy()` to be compatible with IE8 or use `.bind()` for modern browers.

```
setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
    // this.click(); // if this = $(".btn")
}, this), 100);
```

To explain it properly:

```
$(function(){
    var btn = $('.btn');

    btn.click(function(ev){
        var el = $(ev.currentTarget), // same as $(this) but too many "thisses" can be confusing ^^
            title = el.prop('title');

        $.get('getOutput', {}, function(){
            // success ajax get
            // how to refer again to this function? Doing again the $('.btn').click event
            setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
                this.click();
            }, el), 100);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think it wouldn't work in this specific case because the scope is already different inside his `$.get` callback. It wouldn't reference to his element.

Comment: Hence the comment `if this is $(".btn")` but that may not be so clearly explained.

Comment: Ofcourse, using this approach is only usefull when things become more complicated. In your example it may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering the click event again, you may be better off naming the click event handler function and calling it again from within your `setTimeout`.

```
var handleButtonClick = function() {
    $title = $(this).attr('title');
    $.get('getOutput', {}, function() {
        // success ajax get    
        setTimeout(handleButtonClick , 100);
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('.btn').click(handleButtonClick);
});
```